# force refresh of docker image when updated in registry / kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Using Kubernetes for deployment:

Considering I have a Dockerfile, I build, then push to registry.
If I run a container on a host, the image gets pulled and the container is ran.

Now, if i update the Dockerfile, build and push again, **without changing its tag** then the image is changed in the registry, but the host has the image pulled, and it doesn't seem to go look for updates.

How do i force a pull to get the latest image when running a container? 
I can manually pull the image, but I'd like to know if there is a 'formal way' of doing this (in the pod or rc templates?)

Thanks for insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set an `imagePullPolicy` of `Always` on the container

Comment: you mean in the container declaration in the pod, or rc template? What's the syntax exactly? and is there a place to find all the possible syntax for these? the Kubernetes docs tend to be very dispersed

Comment: almost i guess: i get invalid:spec.template.spec.containers[0].imagePullPolicy: unsupported value 'PullAlways': supported values: Always, IfNotPresent, Never  so i'll set to 'Always'